# sometimes my pg_restore or mongorestore gets stuck

Tags: python, postgresql, mongodb, popen

```
print 'restore db1'
run_command('pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d db1 -v "/var/lib/project/backup/db1.backup" -c')
print '--- wait 3 seconds'
time.sleep(3)

print 'restore db2'
run_command('pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d db2 -v "/var/lib/project/backup/db2.backup" -c')
print '--- wait 3 seconds'
time.sleep(3)

print 'restoring mongodb'
run_command('/var/lib/project/bbds/mongodb-linux/bin/mongorestore /var/lib/project/backup/dump --drop')
print '--- wait 3 seconds'
time.sleep(3)
```

My `run_command` is basically taken from [this](http://pastebin.com/4gLsNb37).

On my console:

```
python ignition.py --load-fixtures
For safety, this process will run for about one minute.
setup LDAP
restore db1
['pg_restore', '-i', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', '5432', '-U', 'postgres', '-d', 'db1', '-v', '/var/lib/project/backup/db1.backup', '-c']
Password:
```

It just stuck after entering password. Nothing happens afterward. I am not sure if it's resource busy. `pg_restore` is still running according `ps au|grep pg_restore` and `mongorestore` is not. So it must be stuck with the first restore. I don't think it's memory full either because my virtual machine has only 512mb and it's always full, and always uses the swap memory.

How do we know what it is doing? Sometimes it stucks on restoring mongo. So all these operations can cause problem. 
How should I troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

---

When I killed the process , I get this traceback: http://pastebin.com/Cnv9P6HW
A reboot will "solve" the problem. It will allow me to run the script without problem. But that's not stable. We will end up in limbo sometimes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `pg_restore` and `mongorestore` seems to be independent.  I would try:

- running each command directly from a command line (i.e. not via Python `do_command()`)
- putting these into separate scripts so you can work out which command is hanging

Your mention of only 512MB RAM and always using swap suggests there isn't enough free memory on this VM.  What exactly does "stuck" mean?  If the VM actually gets wedged and needs to be restarted, it most likely has run out of both RAM and swap.  If you can still login but the restore script appears to be running for a longer than expected time, I would try to understand the resource usage using [performance monitoring tools](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/iostat-vmstat-mpstat-examples/) like `iostat` and `vmstat`.

Comment: Thanks. I will make a response first before I investigate on this issue further with other suggestions you gave. I've checked `free -m` and swap was not full, so it doesn't seem like it's doing something weird. Could it be the database is locked by another process? I have tried to `strace` pg_restore. It hung there. See here (http://blog.kimiensoftware.com/2011/06/pg_restore-hanging-on-remote-create-index-344) It didn't say `Poll` or anything. Just hung on the line `Process 32305 attached - interrupt to quit` Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner: have you tried asking the question on the PostgreSQL mailing list?  Some more details would help, eg: your O/S, specific version of pg_restore/pg_dump (i.e. `pg_restore --version`, `pg_dump --version`), and pg_dump options used.  I haven't encountered the same problem you're having, where pg_restore apparently mysteriously hangs.

Comment: @CppLearner: another suggestion to try ... see if you can [view the executing queries](http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/) while pg_restore is running (or "hung").

Comment: Please bear with me. I am a bit busy today as I need to roll out a demo machine. I will double check on this! Thanks for the super helping here.